# GlusterFS No Space

Tags: glusterfs

I create a cluster of glusterfs by vm's

I have 2 brick :

1. 192.168.42.x -> 1GB
2. 192.168.42.y -> 1GB

`create volume glv1 192.168.42.x:/exp/sda3/brick 192.168.42.y:/exp/sda3/brick`

`volume start glv1`

and then i mount the distributed FS in my local system

`mount -t glusterfs 192.168.42.x:glv1 /gluster`

then i copy a file with size 890MB

after this when i try to copy another file ( 300 MB ) to my volume

I faced with this error :

`No space left on device`

so the cluster dont try to save the file at another brick ( only save the files into the address I mount the volume through that )

why ? :/

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case both the files are getting "hashed" into same brick and it runs out of space.

If you touch around 100 files, few files will be (hashed and) present in brick1 and few files will be at brick2. files are getting hashed based on filename.

For example, if you create file delete the file - create with the same name - it will hash(and present) to brick where it was created earlier.

So, in your case both the files are getting "hashed" into same brick and it runs out of space.

Comment: thanks a lot , can i change the hashing method ( file name base ) ? or this method of hashing is fixed

Comment: @KoLiBer It is fixed - but, hey GlusterFS is open source and you can propose your idea to the community - https://www.gluster.org/community/